# Display last index key of 2D array error strict standards

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to display key of last value for first and 2nd dimension.

I'm using this code to get index keys of values in 2D array, it works but I get a really annoying error

```
echo end(array_keys($patch_array));
```

Error:

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of end() is a pass by reference.  It is that way so it set the internal pointer to the end of the array.

You can fix it by doing:

```
$keys = array_keys($patch_array);
echo end($keys);
```